# Question regarding the application of Cauchy's integral formula in the proof of Gelfands spectral radius formula.

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-algebras, spectral-theory

I was reading through the *Functional Analysis* by *Lax* and stumbled onto a proof that I didn't quite understand. More concretely it is abbout the application of Cauchy's integral formula in the proof of Gelfands spectral radius formula.

Lax argues, that by Cauchy's integral formula
$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_C\frac{\lambda^n}{\lambda-M}d\lambda=M^n,$$
where $C$ is a path in the resolvent set of $M$ that winds once around $\sigma(M)$, and
$$(\lambda-M)^{-1}=\sum_{i=0}^\infty M^i\lambda^{-i-1}$$
holds for any $|\lambda|>\|M\|$. What I don't understand is, that to apply Cauchy's integral formula one needs a holomorphic function on a simply connected set and the path needs to be inside that set. However, $\frac{\lambda^{n-1}}{\lambda-M}$ is only holomorphic on $\rho(M)$ but not on $\sigma(M)$, which is surely inside $\rho(M)$. So how is it valid to argue with Cauchy's integral formula here?

Comment: The function Lax is applying the Cauchy integral formula to is $\lambda^n$, which is holomorphic everywhere. Admittedly this is some generalization of it to Banach algebras which doesn't obviously follow from the usual Cauchy integral formula.